# Sun JDK trigger full gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection

JRockit (1.6) has an option called gcTrigger.By default a full gc is triggered when the old gen fills up. The gc trigger option allows you to trigger a full gc *before* it fills up (or rather when the full gc gets triggered).

I want to know if Sun JDK (1.6) has a similar option. I have not been able to find one so far.

Update : I don't mean a manual gc ! I am referring to an option that mimics the behaviour of gcTrigger in JRockit

Comment: does [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) helps.

Comment: does [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) helps.

Comment: Do you mean like `System.gc();`?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to call the Garbage Collector

```
System.gc();
Runtime.gc();
```

But, keep in mind this doesn't means the Garbage collection will be immediately triggered.